# Android photo sync without google

Tags: android, cloud-storage

I would like to decrease my dependence from the Google. Particularly, I don't wish to

- allow google to remove image/video metadata, without I asked it from them (but allow them to process it)
- allow google to have access to my private photos (videos)
- pay google for giving a larger storage data than 16GB, while I could buy a hard disk roughly in their price for a year
- allow google to irrecoverably decrease the quality of my photos
- tolerate such "jokes" from them, like the separation of the google drive and google photos.

However, I would still like to have the nice features of the google photos / cloud storage. Particularly:

- on all my android devices, where I have google photos, the photos are uploaded to the google automatically, if I have a wifi connection
- my synchronized, and old photos (videos) are automatically deleted from my devices (but not from the cloud storage)
- my new photos (created by my other androids) in the server storage are automatically downloaded to my devices

I have my own servers, on which I have full control: I decide, how big HDD I buy into them, and what services do I want to run on them.

However, I have much lesser control over my android devices: I can use only apps which are allowed by the google, and many of them wants regularly cash from me, what I don't want to pay.

Most ideally, I would like to have a google photos, what is using my own sftp server, and not the Google. Alternatively, anything on the server side is okay, what I can do with a Linux (for example, WebDav).

I tried [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite&hl=de) until now. It can synchronize data over ssh, but it can't automatically delete my old photos.

I tried also [PhotoSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchbyte.photosync&hl=de). Beside the disadvantage of the FolderSync, it also wants money for sftp support.

Comment: Would Nextcloud be an option? AFAIK the Nextcloud app also includes a photo sync feature (not sure about the delete part, though). And it's FOSS, server as well as client app. As for FolderSync: IIRC when chosing "unidirection sync", there was an option to "delete after upload".

Comment: @Izzy Thanks! I am experimenting with Nextcloud. "delete after upload" is not enough exact what I want. What I want: "delete the oldest files after upload, but only if the flash of my phone is nearly full". Be back soon.

Comment: Afraid that exact functionality is not available in any app I know (except for the one we both don't want to use). Could be possible to establish that via Tasker or MacroDroid, though (at least FolderSync has Tasker support; or use a script with `rsync` so you can check "sync OK && space low => remove_oder_than").